# when i try to install angular error occurs

Tags: node.js, angular

> C:\Users\guest02>npm install -g @angular/cli npm ERR! code ETARGET npm
>   ERR! notarget No matching version found for
>   @angular-devkit/architect@0.900.1. npm ERR! notarget In most cases you
>   or one of your dependencies are requesting npm ERR! notarget a package
>   version that doesn't exist. npm ERR! notarget npm ERR! notarget It was
>   specified as a dependency of '@angular/cli' npm ERR! notarget
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\guest02\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-07T06_28_56_030Z-debug.log

Comment: Maybe you should try to download a specific version. npm install -g @angular/cli@version_id

Comment: This error is normally related to a wrong cache enry in either your own client or your hosted package manager (nexus). To fix that error it is normally enought to clean the NPM cache (npm cache clean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the following steps. Make sure you have installed **node.js** in your computer.

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Once its installed check the version of the Angular to make sure its installed properly.

```
ng version
```

Comment: Running ng version was what turned the tide for me after spinning my wheels for hours. It showed that a component of ng had an internal error, which I could correct by specifically installing that component.